# Change the value of span using Javascript or Jquery using <input> or text attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change span value to `<span class='tag'>test_succeed</span>`,

I tried "input" but it doesn't work, any idea ?

```html
<span class="tag" id="tag-option">
  <input type='hidden' name='tag-value' value='' id="test-input">
  <span class="close"></span>
</span>
<script>
  document.getElementById('test-input').value = "test_succeed";
</script>
```

Comment: Your input type is `hidden` so it might be related.

Comment: Can you give more info? Why is your input hidden? Are you using a server-side framework and making a form? If you want to change in response to changing value of input, use event listeners.

Comment: @DimiVi I tried to change the value inside "span" by adding an input any other idea would do the job ?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on page load? If you want to add `test_succeed` to the span, you can use `let span = document.getElementById('tag-option'); span.innerText = 'test_succeed';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only trying to add text to the `span`, you don't need an input element. You can use the `innerText` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

```html
<span class="tag" id="tag-option">
  <span class="close"></span>
</span>
<script>
  document.getElementById('tag-option').innerText = 'test_succeed';
</script>
```

##### EDIT

To keep the "close" span, you can use `prepend`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend

```html
<span class="tag" id="tag-option">
  <span class="close">Close Span</span>
</span>
<script>
  document.getElementById('tag-option').prepend('test_succeed');
</script>
```

Comment: One more thing, I want to add ```<span class="close"></span>``` with "test_succeed"

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about `<tag>value</tag>` you are referring to a DOM object, in this particular case you are trying to update the inner HTML for that tag.

So you can do it using:

`document.getElementById('my_id').innerHTML = 'my text';`

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Or using jQuery:

`$('#my_id').html('my text');`

(https://api.jquery.com/html/)